# How to reload another controller from controller in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i am developing web site in angularjs. I am using ui-routing. I want to reload state after the user login. I have index.html and app.js. Below is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('RoslpApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider)
{
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/HomePage');
    $stateProvider
   .state('Login', {
       url: '/Login',
       templateUrl: 'App/Registration/Login.html',
       controller: 'Login'
   });
});

app.controller('RoslpAppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
 var cookieloginid = $cookieStore.get('LoginID');
    if (cookieloginid != null) {
        //This will reoload
        var id = document.getElementById('ProfileDropdown');
        id.innerHTML = $scope.ProfileDropdown = ' <ul>' +
            '<li><a href="#/userProfile">User Profile</a></li>' +
            '<li>test1</li>' +
           ' <li onclick="logout(event)">logout</li>' +
        '</ul>';
        $scope.dp == false;
    }
```

Below is my login code.

```
  $http.post(url, sub).then(function (response) {
                        setTimeout(function () { 
//Trigger or reload RoslpAppController controller
LoginSuccess(response); }, 1000);
                    }, function (error) {
                        setTimeout(function () { HideLoader(); }, 1000);
                        toastr.error($filter('translate')(error.data.msg));
                    });
```

After login success i will get login id and i will store it in cookie. In RoslpAppController controller i want to check if the cookie exists or not on login. May i know how this can be done? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload AngularJS Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170625/reload-angularjs-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You have to transition to a state on getting success response from server after your login POST call.
To transition to a state use - `$state.go("<statename>",{params},{reload : true})`

If you don't have any state for `RoslpAppController` then make one.

Edit after OP's comment :

```
.state('Roslp', {
    url: '/Roslp',
    templateUrl: 'App/Registration/View.html',
    controller: 'RoslpAppController'
});
```

In the templateUrl give the view that you want to load after login.
Use `$state.go("Roslp",{params},{reload : true})` now.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have state for RoslpAppController  because that is in app.js file. May i know how can i create state to it?

Comment: I have created a plunker. plnkr.co/edit/ZJJZLqJWRPOk4SKlvAa8?p=preview On login success i want to reload controller RoslpAppController