# qtip2 for HTML elements created in an angularjs function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, qtip, qtip2

I have this part of HTML

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-bind-html="tmpfcn(thing.text, thing.objects)"></li>
</ul>
```

Which for every iteration returns some text with hyperlinks inside. e.g.

> I like the  [winter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter)

I want to use qtip for each of the hyperlinks with different content for each hyperlink. 
I've defined a qtip directive which I've tested with an HTML element like this

```
<span qtip="This is the message printed"> hover over me</span>
```

and it works just fine.

I've looked at many solutions for similar problems like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934315/angularjs-binding-jquery-qtip2-plugin) but I couldn't get my code to work.

Could someone provide some guidelines? An example would bereally helpful as well.

Comment: The way you've used `ng-repeat` will give you a new `ul` for every item, which will contain a single `li`. I assume you intended for 1 `ul` with multiple `li`s?

Comment: Actually I've tested it and it displays the format I wanted so I'm fine with that for the moment.